# Getting only the id entity the other fields null Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have weird problem with Doctrine and Symfony 3, I've spent two days now without any result.

My problem is when I get an entity from my database, I get only the id and the other fields `null` or they have vales

Here is my code:

```
 $utilsateur = $em->getRepository('GestionAccesBundle:Client')->findBy(array('id_client'=>1));
```

here is the debug result:
[image: description]

and here is my data base row:

[image: description]

Answer (score 3):

It's a proxy object generated by Doctrine. Real data will be loaded from database when you try to access it for the first time.

It's called lazy loading. It prevents unnecessary queries to DB.

Comment: There's nothing to resolve here. Just use it as it would be fulfilled object. After you use e.g. some getter like `getAddress` for the first time, then the object should contain real data.

Comment: can u expailn more plz ?!! every time i call entity i should do this !!